# Machine Learning in Paper making machines

Tags: machine-learning

The company I work for produces packaging paper on a mass scale; my task is to see if machine learning would be able to help identify paper breaks on the machines before they actually happen.  We have sensors and high speed camera systems on the machine for real-time analysis.

I do not know which machine learning algorithms would be applicable for this problem?

In the paper making process, a continuous sheet of paper is formed and fed through a series of machines.  If the paper breaks, the process must be restarted.  We have machines for detecting a paper break after one has already occurred, but my goal is to use machine learning to detect a break before it happens.

Could an algorithm be created that could constantly analyze many different points on the machine and based on that data be able to predict a sheet break or not?

Comment: Can you give us more information regarding the current techniques using these sensors and cameras. What kind of sensors are they? And how do they predict these breaks?

Comment: Since we don't know anything about paper making, you'll have to explain how and why it happens.

Comment: In light of the new information, you have a [machine vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_vision) problem. I would continuously record video of the paper as it is rolled onto the drum, feed it to a [convolutional neural network](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/). The goal would be to predict the response of your RYECO. I assume it either passes or fails, with no gradation, so you have a classification problem.